# How do I provide a different prompt in Java using Scanner?

Tags: java

```
public static void promptGuessRound(Scanner console) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int num = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
    int input = 0;
    System.out.println("The number is between 1 and 1000");
    do{
        try {
            System.out.print("Guess the number: ");
            input = console.nextInt();
            if (input > num) {
                System.out.println("The number is lower");
            } else if (input < num) {
                System.out.println("The number is higher");
            } else if (input > 1000 || input < 1) {
                System.out.print("That won't work, try again > ");
                console.nextInt();
            }
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.print("That won't work, try again > ");
        }
        console.nextLine();
    } while (input != num);

}
```

This is just a sample of my code which is essentially a guessing game, but looking at the `promptGuessRound()` method, how can I provide the user with a different prompt when they enter an invalid input (either a number out of range or an input mismatch).

This is because whenever the loop restarts, it adds the original prompt after providing them with the invalid prompt. So how can I solve this problem?

Additionally, if solving the problem does not allow the Scanner to read the value that was typed in after that prompt, how can I make it do that?

Sample Output during one iteration in case it's not clear enough:

```
/*
The number is between 1 and 1000
Guess the number: p
That won't work, try again > Guess the number: 
*/
```

Comment: Put the initial prompt outside the loop?

Comment: Oh right, then I can just prompt it again in each condition. Thanks very much

Comment: Make it be a string input, check if you can parse it to int, if you get an error with ```try/catch```, print the error message and try again